# Protractor returning the value null or undefined while checking the check box selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to execute a BDD testcase using protractor and cucumber. 
The code looks like below.

```
   var chai = require('chai');
   var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
   chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
   var expect = chai.expect;

   var myStepDefinitionsWrapper = function () {

      if(isTrue(orgDownloadCase)) {
      createOrgBasic.orgDownloadCases.getAttribute('checked').then(function (checked)
      {
            console.log("Checked" +checked);
            if (checked == true) {
                createOrgBasic.orgDownloadCases.click();
            }
        });
    }

  };
```

When i am trying to execute the above mentioned code , its displaying the below exception. Checked value is printed as null or undefined. New to protrcator, any help would be appreciable.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined   at
>   World.
>   (E:\PFH\bdd\organization-management\Organisaton_Management_Feature\feature-bdd-UI\step_definitions\CreateOrganizationSteps.js:160:50)
>   at formatter.handleStepResultEvent

Comment: What is `createOrgBasic` and where does that come from?  The exception means that it doesn't have a property named `orgDownloadCases`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I was doing it wrong and got the solution. Once i do isDisplayed which will give promise , i used to assign it to variable using a function. so when i did that, it was giving the boolean value.